# TRichViewEdit 16.10, language for Popup menu

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on an application written under C++ Embarcadero that holds several TRichViewEdit objects.
All works fine except one thing: all the popup menus (for copy/paste/hyperlink...) are in French (which is fine) except one that is in English.
I tried to set the language field of the PopupMenu->ControlPanel, but it has no effect.

Where can I find the appropriate property to set the popup menu so that it is displayed in French, like all the other ones ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm finally answering my own question: during initialisation of the form where the TRichViewEdit object is used, just localize it using

```
RVA_LocalizeForm(myObject);
```